# (RIGHT(CONVERT part of varchar 103 to 120 DATETIME to display results as 120

Tags: sql, vba, sql-server-2008, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the below query bringing out all of the correct results I need for any specific date. However, my client would like to be able to search by any single month at a time, avoiding selecting each day of the month individually. I assumed I would be able to convert a portion of the date (month+year), convert it to another format, and then use that. Currently displaying as 05/2016 (103), but I need to be able to search as 2016-05% (120) for results to appear.
The code is to be placed inside an Access VBA form.

```
SELECT 
    os.shop, os.prefix, 
    Rep_date AS FDate, 
    SUM(RC) AS Fulfilled, 
    SUM(RF) AS Refunded, 
    SUM(OS) AS TotalOS, 
    SUM(CA) AS TotalCA, 
    SUM(RET) AS TotalRET, 
    SUM(LOST) AS TotalLOST, 
    SUM(SHOR) AS TotalSHOR, 
    SUM(Total) AS Total, 
    CAST((CAST(SUM(RC) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) / CAST(SUM(Total) AS DECIMAL(9, 4))) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) AS RCPC, 
    CAST((CAST(SUM(RF) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) / CAST(SUM(Total) AS DECIMAL(9, 4))) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) AS RFPC, 
    CAST((CAST(SUM(OS) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) / CAST(SUM(Total) AS DECIMAL(9, 4))) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) AS OSPC, 
    CAST((CAST(SUM(CA) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) / CAST(SUM(Total) AS DECIMAL(9, 4))) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) AS CAPC, 
    CAST((CAST(SUM(RET) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) / CAST(SUM(Total) AS DECIMAL(9, 4))) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) AS RETPC, 
    CAST((CAST(SUM(LOST) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) / CAST(SUM(Total) AS DECIMAL(9, 4))) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) AS LOSTPC, 
    CAST((CAST(SUM(SHOR) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) / CAST(SUM(Total) AS DECIMAL(9, 4))) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) AS SHORPC, 
    SUM(Orders) AS TotalOrders, 
    SUM(AmazonShipped) AS AmazonShipped, 
    SUM(AmazonCancelled) AS AmazonCancelled, 
    SUM(AmazonUnshipped) AS AmazonUnshipped, 
    CAST((CAST(SUM(AmazonShipped) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) / CAST(SUM(Orders) AS DECIMAL(9, 4))) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) AS AmazonShippedPC, 
    CAST((CAST(SUM(AmazonCancelled) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) / CAST(SUM(Orders) AS DECIMAL(9, 4))) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) AS AmazonCancelledPC, 
    CAST((CAST(SUM(AmazonUnshipped) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) / CAST(SUM(Orders) AS DECIMAL(9, 4))) AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) AS AmazonUnshippedPC, 
    p.Description 
FROM 
    OrderStatusSummary os 
LEFT JOIN 
    Prefix p ON os.prefix = p.prefix 
GROUP BY 
    Rep_date, os.shop, os.prefix, p.Description 
HAVING 
   (CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), Rep_date, 120) AS DATETIME) = CONVERT(DATETIME, '25/05/2016', 103)) 
ORDER BY 
    CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), Rep_date, 120) AS DATETIME) DESC
```

The above is working as a means of searching by a full date, the below is what I have tried to use to search by month/year only, to show you kind of what i'm trying to achieve. It is however not working.

```
HAVING (RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), Rep_date, 103),7) = '05/2016')
```

The only part of code I have changed is the HAVING compared to the top block.

Comment: The `HAVING` clause is intended for aggregate function conditions. Perhaps you should have a derived table (or cte)?

Comment: Table changes are out of my control, unfortunately.

Comment: A derived table is simply a subquery with an alias.

Comment: Derived tables and cte's are SQL constructions, used to simplify queries.

Comment: If `Rep_date` is of `date(time(2))` datatype, why not simply use `where MONTH(Rep_date) = 5 AND YEAR(Rep_date) = 2016`?

Comment: Filtering on function results is usually slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question after coming back to it a few days later with a fresh head..

Since the Rep_date is a text field rather than a date field, I don't need any date conversions on it.

```
HAVING LEFT(Rep_date, 7) = '2016-05'
```

Works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Create 2 variables, named startDate and endDate with your vba code.  Make startDate the 1st day of the year-month in question and endDate the first day of the following month.

Step 2 - Use these variables as query parameters for sql having this logic:

```
where rep_date >= startDate
and rep_date < endDate
```